# Determine if binary tree is BST haskell

Tags: haskell, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to write a bool function to return True if a binary tree is a bst using recursion, and I need a little guidance on haskell syntax.

I understand that for a binary tree to be a bst, the left subtree must always contain only nodes less than the head. and the right subtree must always contain only nodes greater than the head. I was structuring my function as such:

```
isBST :: Tree -> Bool       --recieve Tree, return bool
isBST (Lead i) = True       --return true if its only one leaf in tree
isBST (Node h l r) = if (((isBST l) < h) && ((isBST r) > h)) then True else False   
--return true if left subtree < head AND right subtree > head
```

But this code results in the error:

> Couldn't match expected type ‘Bool’ with actual type ‘Int’

Referring to the `< h` and `> h`  parts specifically. Is it something wrong with my haskell formatting? Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look at `isBST l < h` - what type is `h` and what is `isBST l`, I think you need to make your 2nd line a bit more complex, `isBST l &&isBST r &&...`.

Comment: FYI `if x then True else False` is just  `x`.

Comment: `the left subtree must always contain only nodes less than the head` and how do you express this condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Martin, I'd recommend you to look at Willem's answer.

Another thing, you could also use your `maxInt` function that you asked in a previous question to define this function:

```
isBST (Node h l r) = ... (maxInt l) ... -- at some point we will need to use this
```

Taking your definition of BSTs:

> I understand that for a binary tree to be a bst, the left subtree must
>   always contain only nodes less than the head. and the right subtree
>   must always contain only nodes greater than the head.

I'll add that also the subtrees of a node should be BSTs as well.

So we can define this requirement with:

```
isBST (Node h l r) =
  ((maxInt l) < h) -- the left subtree must contain nodes less than the head
  && ((minInt r) > h) -- the right must contain nodes greater than the head
  && (...) -- the left subtree should be a BST
  && (...) -- the right subtree should be a BST
```

Recall that you might need to define `minInt :: Tree -> Int`, as you probably know how to do that.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it something wrong with my haskell formatting?

No, it is a semantical error. You write:

```
(isBST l) < h
```

So this means you ask Haskell to determine whether `l` is a binary search tree, which is `True` or `False`, but you can not compare `True` or `False` with `h`. Even if you could (some languages see `True` as `1` and `False` as `0`), then it would still be incorrect, since we want to know whether *all* nodes in the left subtree are less than `h`.

So we will somehow need to define bounds. A way to do this is to pass parameters through the recursion and perform checks. A problem with this is that the root of the tree for example, has no bounds. We can fix this by using a `Maybe Int` is a boundary: if it is `Nothing`, the boundary is "inactive" so to speak, if it is `Just b`, then the boundary is "active" with value `b`.

In order to make this check more convenient, we can first write a way to check this:

```
checkBound :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> Maybe a -> a -> Bool
checkBound _ Nothing _ = True
checkBound f (Just b) x = f b x
```

So now we can make a "sandwich check" with:

```
sandwich :: Ord a => Maybe a -> Maybe a -> a -> Bool
sandwich low upp x = checkBound (<) low x && checkBound (>) upp x
```

So `sandwich` is given a lowerbound and an upperbound (both `Maybe a`s), and a value, and checks the lower and upper bounds.

So we can write a function `isBST'` with:

```
isBST' :: Maybe Int -> Maybe Int -> Tree -> Bool
isBST' low upp ... = ....
```

There are two cases we need to take into account: the `Leaf x` case, in which the "sandwich constraint" should be satisfied, and the `Node h l r` case in which `h` should satisfy the "sandwich constraint" and furthermore `l` and `r` should satsify different sandwhich constraints. For the `Leaf x` it is thus like:

```
isBST' low upp (Leaf x) = sandwich low upp x
```

For the node case, we first check the same constraint, and then enforce a sandwich between `low` and `h` for the left part `l`, and a sandwich between `h` and `upp` for the right part `r`, so:

```
isBST' low upp (Node h l r) = sandwich low upp h &&
                              isBST' low jh l &&
                              isBST' jh upp r
    where jh = Just h
```

Now the only problem we still have is to call `isBST'` with the root element: here we use `Nothing` as intial bounds, so:

```
isBST :: Tree -> Bool
isBST = isBST' Nothing Nothing
```

There are of course other ways to enforce constraints, like passing and updating functions, or by implement four variants of the `isBST'` function that check a subset of the constraints.

Comment: An easier way to check bounds is with functions. No bound is `const True` and an upper bound of `r` is `(<= r)` (or `(< r)` if you prefer). An interval (finite or not) is just a pair of functions.

Comment: @n.m.: yeah, or we can define four variants of the function. It was more to define an example that is (hopefully) easy to understand.

Comment: Rather than maintaining a pair of Maybe Int bounds, it is much simpler to just do an in-order traversal of the tree and test whether the resulting list is sorted: it will be sorted iff the tree is a proper search tree.

Answer (score 1):

I like Willem Van Onsem's pedagogical approach in his answer.

I was going to delete my answer, but am going to post a "correction" instead, at the risk of being wrong again:

```
data Tree = Empty | Node Int Tree Tree deriving show

isBST :: Tree -> Bool

isBST Empty = True
isBST (Node h l r) = f (<=h) l && f (>=h) r && isBST l && isBST r
   where
     f _ Empty = True
     f c (Node h l r) = c h && f c l && f c r
```

Note that I'm using Wikipedia's definition of BST, that

> the key in each node must be greater than or equal to any key stored
>   in the left sub-tree, and less than or equal to any key stored in the
>   right sub-tree.

Comment: Nope this doesn't work. And your data structure is broken (can you represent a tree with an even number of elements?)

Comment: This does not work, since it does not forces that all subelements on the left are less than the value and vice versa.

Comment: Hope you guys can comment on the update; just trying to learn here

Comment: @Aky: now it is semantically correct (+1), but it is a bit inefficient, since for every node, you will check all the subnodes. But you thus check each node multiple times (for different bounds).